# How to find a point P in △ ABC,△ PAB,△ PBC, the△ PCA inscribed circle radius are equal?

Tags: geometry

How to find a point P in △ ABC,

△ PAB,△ PBC, the△ PCA inscribed circle radius are equal?

Comment: I suggest setting coordinates.

Comment: it is a hard problem. I have solutions for Isosceles, but haven't figure out the common one.

Answer (score 0):

Is the triangle ABC in the cartesian plane? try to picture it in the cartesian plane. How is the point P? in cartesian coordinates? In terms of A,B,and C? Try to draw 3 cirles of the same area, with at least two touching each other, if you draw tangents at the other sides of the circles and form a triangle then P is the midpoint of the line joining the centres of the two circles.